# How do API providers typically measure and bill for API calls per user?

Tags: api, kubernetes, cloud

I want to build k8s in an on-premises environment and provide an API for a deployed service.
As an API provider, I want to measure and bill API usage per user.
How does a typical API provider build this system?

I will be outputting API logs from Nginx ingress, do you deploy a separate server to extract and calculate these logs?
Or can we leverage nginx functionality?
Or, if not on-premises, can I utilize an API Gateway provided by the cloud?
If so, how do you usually utilize it? (For example, do you store the user-specific count information in redis when calling the API... etc)

I have no expertise in this area.
I'm just wondering if there is a very common and typical way to do it.

Thank you in advance